# Conversion from lat-long to Cartesian coordinates 's result is different with real location

Tags: monogame

I'm trying to put building from real lat-long in my Monogame app (4 buildings in my school, please check the image with the blue circles)

But after some convert method, it went terribly wrong (please check image)

Please  help me find out what's wrong.

My code:

```
 public List<float> Gps2Cartesian(float latitude_degree, float longitude_degree, float elevation)
    {
        cartesResult = new List<float>();
        var longtitude_rad = DegreeToRadian(longitude_degree);
        var latitude_rad = DegreeToRadian(latitude_degree);

        var n = a / Math.Sqrt(1 - e2 * Math.Sin(latitude_rad) * Math.Sin(latitude_rad));
        var cartes_X = (n + elevation) * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Cos(longtitude_rad);    //ECEF x (z in right - handed system) (m)
        var cartes_Y = (n + elevation) * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Sin(longtitude_rad);    //ECEF y (x in right - handed system) (m)
        var cartes_Z = (n * (1 - e2) + elevation) * Math.Sin(latitude_rad);          //ECEF z (y in right-handed system) (m)

        cartesResult.Add((float)cartes_Y);
        cartesResult.Add((float)cartes_Z);
        cartesResult.Add((float)cartes_X);

        return cartesResult;
    }
```

And this is debug result:

> D3      X:5730549      Y:2271896      Z:-162645005
>
> C2      X:5730621      Y:2272063      Z:-162594705
>
> C9      X:5730595      Y:2272005      Z:-1626123
>
> C1     X:5730521      Y:2272123      Z:-1626228

Thank you !

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've no experience in this, but I would reccomend you to use a `Vector3` instead of a `List<float>`... Just saying..